# Passing value to static page Golang

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang. how to I pass value to static page?

suppose I have this code :

```
// webtes project main.go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/sayName", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        name := "Jon Snow"
        http.ServeFile(writer, r, "static/sayName.html")/*How do I pass 'name' to this static page and print it?*/
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```

static/sayName.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>{/*print name here*/}</body>
</html>
```

I want to pass "name" variable to the static page "sayName.html" and print that there. How do I achieve this? thks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach it to make `sayName.html` an [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/), and execute it on each request.

Then your handler is something like:

```
func templateHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
   tplTxt,err := ioutil.ReadFile(...)
   //error handling
   tpl := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(string(tplTxt)))
   templateData := map[string]interface{}{"Name":"Jon Snow"}
   tpl.Execute(w, templateData)
}
```

And your html template can use `{{.Name}}` to insert the name.

You should cache the parsed templates and handle errors better, but thats the general idea.

Comment: Many thanks!. Btw. how do I perform looping in static page?

Comment: {{range .SomeList}} ... {{.SomeField}} ... {{end}}